# Best practice of using lucene.net within Asp.net

Tags: c#, lucene.net

Would like to integrate lucene.net 4.8 within a Asp.net website with NRT (Near Realtime Search) capabilities.

Don't know exactly how I have to use reader and writer classes (single or multi instances and so on) like the Searchermanager class for example.

So is there any Best practice usage pattern here when updating the Index regulary?

As a side note...I would like to keep my index in sync with my relational database as accurate as possible.

Comment: Rather than asking about "best practices", which are considered off-topic on SO, I'd consider editing your question asking, simply, how to do this.  Not the best way.  See [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265928/is-a-best-practice-question-off-topic) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot say, that I know the best practices, but you can explore some of my findings:
https://github.com/mihasic/LuceneSearch

Basically, there's a facade `Index` to explore, it which takes care of most of the operations.